# SharePoint 2013 - Project Summary Web Part Not Displaying "Add Task" & "Edit List" Options

Tags: 2013, web-part, project

I created a site template which needed to be applied to other subsites. Within that template was a Web Part of "Content Rollup" - "Project Summary". By default the "Add Task" and "Edit List" options displayed. When the template was applied to the other subsites these options did not display, along with views that were created within other Web Parts but is besides my point.

If I were to re-drop a Web Part on the original site, from the template were it originally displayed, it will show up. Now if I re-dropped it on the cloned subsites from the template were it is not showing up there is no change, the "Add Task" and "Edit List" options do not display.

I have verified that the Edit Web Part settings match, also verified that "Manage Site Features" properties match (e.g. Project Functionality, Access App, Following Content, Getting Started, SharePoint Server Enterprise Site features, Site Feed, Team Collaboration Lists, Wiki Page Home Page, Workflow Task Content Type).

[image: Add Task & Edit List Options]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **`+ADD TASK & EDIT LIST`** option is **only** available with `SharePoint Task List` Project Type.

[image]

**In case,** the Project Type is `Enterprise Project`, this option will be missing because you **must** add the project tasks via the `Project Schedule PDP` as shown below. (Or via the `Microsoft Project`).

> **Check also additional reasons** at [Missing the "ADD TASK - EDIT LIST" Options in the Project Summary Web Part](https://blog.devoworx.net/2018/03/11/missing-add-task-edit-list-options-in-the-project-summary-webpart/)

Comment: The screen shot was generated by using the Project Summary from the Content Rollup without needing any interaction from Microsoft Project, Project Server or any PWA settings. Why would it not be set to display as default under the same root, for instance when creating subsite A it displays and then adding subsite B it doesn't display?

Comment: Check the attached link, it will provide you more detail about missing these options in PSWP

Comment: Thank you for all of the clarification and your help. The link cleared up all of my questions. Once a new task was added it generated the options and 'fixed' my issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. First make sure that under PWA Site Settings the "Project Functionality" site feature is activated. Project online has it off by default. This feature adds project management functionality to a site. It includes tasks, a calendar, and web parts on the home page of the site.
2. Under Connected SharePoint Sites, select project and click on synchronize or activate depending on version of Project online.